# Fill a volume with spheres from a particles generator

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

I'd like fill a volume with spheres from a particles generator

Maybe I can use Rigid Body options
but I don't know how I can

Could you help ?

It a sphere volume with Solidify modifier

I tried with Blender 2.78a I have some crashes to apply Rigid Body informations to spheres objects generated by particles generator. What could I do to fill the volume 
with spheres ?

EDIT: I use three Arrays Modifiers and use I copied Rigid Body informations from Active Object

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What kind of volume? What should it look like? Maybe add some images with desired result.

Comment: If I understand correctly this should help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haS3B6q82kY

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63812/how-to-make-foam-with-bubbles-beer-bath

Comment: Is Collision option useful for this task ?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If I am correct that this is the effect that you are trying to achieve, the most important thing is enabling collision on the volume sphere, not rigid body simulation.

A quick visual walk-through of what I did...

### 1. Add three spheres

- Volume sphere
- Emitter sphere
- Particle sphere

[image]

Note: the max draw type of the volume sphere was set to wire to make it easier to see.

### 2. Setup particle system on the emitter

- Give the particles a long lifetime (like 250+)
- Emit them from the volume of the mesh
- Turn off gravity effects
- Set the render mode to object with the particle sphere selected

[image]

### 3. Enable particle collision on the volume sphere

[image]

Note: the default settings work fine if you don't want particle damping/killing.

[image]